Pydantic objects as elements in a polars dataframe get automatically converted to dicts (structs)?
What puzzles me is that when running
class Cat(pydantic.BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: int

cats = [Cat(name="a", age=1), Cat(name="b", age=2)]
df = pl.DataFrame({"cats": cats})
df = df.with_columns(pl.lit(0).alias("acq_num"))

def wrap(batch):
    return Cat(name="c", age=3)

df = df.group_by("acq_num").agg(pl.col("cats").map_batches(wrap, return_dtype=pl.Struct).alias("cats"))

type(df["cats"][0][0])
# dict

the resulting entries are dicts, even though the function "wrap" returns a Cat.
So polars automatically converts it to a dict, calling model_dump of pydantic?
Changing to
df = df.group_by("acq_num").agg(pl.col("cats").map_batches(wrap, return_dtype=pl.Object).alias("cats"))

results in the error:
SchemaError: expected output type 'Object("object", None)', got 'Struct([Field { name: "name", dtype: String }, Field { name: "age", dtype: Int64 }])'; set `return_dtype` to the proper datatype

I am confused by this conversion happening.
How can I prevent it?

Polars already infers the dtype at pl.DataFrame:
cats = [Cat(name="a", age=1), Cat(name="b", age=2)]
df = pl.DataFrame({"cats": cats})

df

shape: (2, 1)
┌───────────┐
│ cats      │
│ ---       │
│ struct[2] │
╞═══════════╡
│ {"a",1}   │
│ {"b",2}   │
└───────────┘

df.schema

Schema([('cats', Struct({'name': String, 'age': Int64}))])

Rather than accessing model_dump, it looks at the dict storing the object's attributes and converts that into a struct:
Cat(name="a", age=1).__dict__

{'name': 'a', 'age': 1}

To avoid this behaviour, set pl.Object for schema:
df = pl.DataFrame({"cats": cats}, schema={'cats': pl.Object})

df

shape: (2, 1)
┌────────────────┐
│ cats           │
│ ---            │
│ object         │
╞════════════════╡
│ name='a' age=1 │
│ name='b' age=2 │
└────────────────┘

type(df.item(0, 'cats'))
__main__.Cat


Now, with map_batches, the expected output is a pl.Series (or a np.array, which it converts). So, here too you need to specify the dtype at construction:
# import numpy as np

def wrap_batch(batch):
    return pl.Series([Cat(name="c", age=3)], dtype=pl.Object)
    # return np.array([Cat(name="c", age=3)], dtype=object) will also work

df = df.group_by("acq_num").agg(
    pl.col("cats").map_batches(wrap_batch, return_dtype=pl.Object).alias("cats")
    )

(Note that the above also works without return_dtype=pl.Object, "but [this] is considered a bug in the user's query".)
type(df.explode('cats').item(0, 'cats'))
__main__.Cat

# you could add `returns_scalar=True` in this trivial example to avoid `explode`


With map_elements, you would only need to worry about the dtype in this case via return_dtype:
def wrap_element(element):
    return Cat(name="c", age=3)

df = df.group_by("acq_num").agg(
    pl.col("cats").map_elements(wrap_element, return_dtype=pl.Object)
    .alias("cats")
    )

type(df.item(0, 'cats'))
__main__.Cat

